# OpenID Connect Single Sign On handling login block

Tags: commerce, authentication-authorization

I am trying to implement an SSO system for my 3 Drupal websites. All the sites are separate domain and not sub-domains. 
Here is the problem:
On the client site, client1.com, I click "Log in with Generic".
I am transferred to the server site, server1.com.
I entered the Username and Password and click Log in. I "authorize this request". I land at the client site, client1.com. But the login block still shows as previous. When I check the cookies in the browser url bar, it shows a cookie is created with client domain name.
I have followed the steps provide by the article [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274367) (https://www.drupal.org/node/2274367).
I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue with SSO. Please help to resolve this issue.